# How to use JavaScript to change a cascading style sheet dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

I found a site that can change css dynamically using JavaScript http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml
like it will have 2 css and you're able to click one of them and change the design of the whole site. But my problem is that for example I changed it into an alternate css then reload it it will jsut change back into the original css. What can I do to make it stay as the css that I chose?

This is the JavaScript

```
function getCookie(cname)
 {
 var name = cname + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
 var c = ca[i].trim();
if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
 return "";
}

// *** TO BE CUSTOMISED ***

 var style_cookie_name = "theme" ;
var style_cookie_duration = 30 ;

   // *** END OF CUSTOMISABLE SECTION ***

function switch_style ( css_title )
{
 // You may use this script on your site free of charge provided
 // you do not remove this notice or the URL below. Script from
// http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml
  var i, link_tag ;
  for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
    i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
    if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
      link_tag[i].title) {
      link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
      if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
        link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
      }
    }
    set_cookie( style_cookie_name, css_title,
      style_cookie_duration );
  }
 }
 function set_style_from_cookie()
 {
   var css_title = getCookie( style_cookie_name );
     alert(css_title);
  if (css_title.length) {
    switch_style( css_title );
  }
 }
  function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
    lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
 {
     alert(cookie_value)
    // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                       ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
                       "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                       "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                      24 * lifespan_in_days +
                       "; path=/" + domain_string ;
    }
     function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
 {

     var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
              alert(cookie_string)
     var re = new RegExp("(^|;)[\s]*" + cookie_name + "=([^;]*)");             
     if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
         var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (re);
         alert(cookie_value)
     return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
  }
    return '' ;
  }
 set_style_from_cookie()
```

css

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="blue"
   href="http://myanimesekai.com/css/newcss.css">
  <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="pink"
   href="http://myanimesekai.com/css/css.css">
```

this is the form

```
<form>
<input type="submit"
  onclick="switch_style('blue');return false;"
  name="theme" value="Blue Theme" id="blue">
<input type="submit"
  onclick="switch_style('pink');return false;"
  name="theme" value="Pink Theme" id="pink">
</form>
```

it says that I have to put the right info on the set cookie part

```
 function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
```

so I changed it into

```
 function set_cookie ( "style", "theme",
7, "myanimesekai.com" )
```

but what happen is that it will not work If I changed it into that. All I want is that if the user picked a style it will stay as that even when he/she reload the page OR go to another page of my site

I already included this part:

```
 <body onload="set_style_from_cookie()">
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you verify that the cookie is actually being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SALgL/
you seem to change the function itself rather than "calling" the function. revert back the set_cookie function as it was with parameters and just change the variables at the top:

```
var style_cookie_name = "theme" ;
var style_cookie_duration = 7 ;
```

also the regex used in get_cookie is malformed and is not working use this function instead:

```
function get_cookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}
```

Comment: I fixed my answer. please apply these and it will work

Comment: uhmmm what it did now is that it prevents my css from loading :( http://myanimesekai.com/Watch/Angel-Beats!-Episode-1.html

Comment: can't seem to open the page? can you edit your question and put full code there?

Comment: okay now, i think the code works, but somehow it cannot find the css file. are you sure it is accessible? i can't for example open http://myanimesekai.com/css/newcss.css

Comment: okay I did some magic and it works fine now!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!! THIS PROBLEM GAVE ME NIGHTMARES AND NOW ITS OVER!!!!!!

Comment: but one last question how can I make it apply for all my pages example http://myanimesekai.com/Watch/Angel-Beats!-Episode-2 click on the Golden Time Episode 3 >>

Comment: because it only apply for that specific page and not the others

Comment: how can I make it apply for all link that has myanimesekai.com on it?